# appcompat-v7 custom button colors

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

is it possible to customize the button colors for appcompat-v7? The default buttons are gray and I would like to change them to green throughout the entire app. setting android:background to a drawable removes the curved edges.

Comment: you can create a style and use it for any button you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file named "shape_btn.xml" in your drawable directory like this, change the android:color to what you like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
       android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        <padding android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
                 android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

and set to button background:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/shape_btn"
    />
```

If you want to apply it to all buttons in your app, change your theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button" >
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_btn</item>
</style>
```

Comment: how can I customize the color for android:state_pressed for your method though?

Comment: Create two shape drawable, and a selector drawable contains them. Or Create a ripple drawable in drawable-v21 directory like this: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_material.xml

Answer (score 4):

Since you're explicity asking on how to do it with `appcompat-v7` - here's the recommended way.
First of all: Creating a new drawable isn't necessary. You can simply change the color of a button by using a theme with the `colorButtonNormal` attribute.

Following an example:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ThemeButton">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#009688</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<!-- other layout elements -->

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeButton" />
```

**Result:**

[image: button showing result]

This way you'll keep the standard elevation and ripple effect when the button is pressed which isn't the case when using a custom drawable. (at least if you're not using a selector)

Comment: Can I upvote you a thousand times? This answer does what I've been trying for the last day. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create a custom layout in your app. In your drawable folder create a xml file named as lets say, custom_button.xml.

Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <solid
                android:color="ColourCode of the colour you Want to give"
                />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Save the xml file and in your activity_main.xml file where you have defined the button, add custom_button as background.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleButton"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>
```

It will work now